# Azure WebApp PageMethod fails

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, scriptmanager, pagemethods

I have created a Azure Web App and published my application from Visual Studio and I can access the website as expected. However, the aspx web pages in the website use calls to PageMethods using the asp.ScriptManager. All works fine if I host through IIS on a web server but any calls when hosted as an Azure Web App returns "Object doesn't support property or method....".

After some more investigation, I get 'Sys' is undefined and checking the network monitor, WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd return a 404. Odd
Does Azure not support this? Or am I missing some configuration?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?  What .NET framework are you compiled against and can you show the specific line of code where you are getting that error?

Comment: Found the solution. I was running the WebApp in Classic mode. Switched to Integrated mode and the script files are delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was running the WebApp in Classic mode. Switched to Integrated mode and the script files are delivered.